# Read the filename of the selected file

Tags: autoit

I am trying to figure out a way to read the file name of a selected file in windows explorer. I tried this but it did not work

```
run ("C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe C:\ProgramData\")
WinWaitActive("ProgramData")
Sleep(2000)

;select the 4th file
Send("{down}{down}{down}")

$index=ControlListView ( "ProgramData", "", "SysListView321", "GetSelected")
ConsoleWrite("$index: " & $index & @CRLF)
$text = ControlListView ( "ProgramData", "", "SysListView321", "GetText",$index)
ConsoleWrite("$text: " & $text & @CRLF)
```

I know that we can do it with `Run("explorer.exe /e,/select," & filename)` but I want an alternate way to this.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? I am sure there is a better way to do it anyway...

Comment: I know it sounds insane to not to use select option for explorer. But we have a plugin built up on explorer and the select option does not work there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As promised ;)

Here is an simpler example without having to download any udf:

```
HotKeySet("{ESC}", "_Exit")

Do
    Sleep(10)
Until WinExists("[REGEXPCLASS:^(Cabinet|Explore)WClass$]")

Local $hWin = WinGetHandle( "[REGEXPCLASS:^(Cabinet|Explore)WClass$]" )
If Not $hWin Then Exit

Local $hItem = "", $hSelection, $sText
WinActivate($hWin)

; Shell object
$oShell = ObjCreate("Shell.Application")

; Find window
For $oWindow In $oShell.Windows()
    If $oWindow.HWND() = $hWin Then ExitLoop
Next

; Selected items
For $oItem In $oWindow.Document.SelectedItems()
    $hItem = $oItem.Name()
Next

While WinExists("[REGEXPCLASS:^(Cabinet|Explore)WClass$]")
    For $oItem In $oWindow.Document.SelectedItems()
        If $oItem.Name() <> $hItem Then
            ConsoleWrite("Name: " & $oItem.Name & @CRLF)    ;Sets or gets the item's name.
            ConsoleWrite("Type: " & $oItem.Type & @CRLF)    ;Contains a string representation of the item's type.
            ConsoleWrite("Path: " & $oItem.Path  & @CRLF)   ;Contains the item's full path and name.
            ConsoleWrite("IsLink: " & $oItem.IsLink  & @CRLF)   ;Indicates whether the item is a shortcut.
            ConsoleWrite("IsFolder: " & $oItem.IsFolder & @CRLF)    ;Indicates whether the item is a folder.
            ConsoleWrite("IsFileSystem: " & $oItem.IsFileSystem & @CRLF)    ;Indicates if the item is part of the file system.
            ConsoleWrite("IsBrowsable : " & $oItem.IsBrowsable & @CRLF) ;Indicates if the item can be hosted inside a browser or Windows Explorer frame.
            ConsoleWrite("GetLink : " & $oItem.GetLink  & @CRLF)    ;Contains the item's ShellLinkObject object, if the item is a shortcut.
            ConsoleWrite("GetFolder : " & $oItem.GetFolder & @CRLF) ;Contains the item's Folder object, if the item is a folder.
            ConsoleWrite("Application : " & $oItem.Application  & @CRLF)    ;Contains the Application object of the folder item.
            ConsoleWrite("Date: " & $oItem.ModifyDate  & @CRLF)   ;yy/mm/dd hh/nn/ss
            ConsoleWrite("Size: " & $oItem.Size & " bytes"& @CRLF)  ;Contains the item's size.
            ;ConsoleWrite("Type: " & Round($oItem.Size / 1000) & " KB"& @CRLF)
            $hItem = $oItem.Name()
        EndIf
    Next
    Sleep(100)
WEnd
ConsoleWrite("Exit" & @LF)

Func _Exit()
    Exit
EndFunc   ;==>_Exit
```

In the first for loop you will have all the names. In the second we simply select every item.
If you need more help let me know

Comment: Thanks. I liked the first solution since it is quite straight forward any additional lib (like UIAutomation). Well can you extend that solution to also display the various attributes that we see in detailed view of Windows Explorer like size, modified date and type. I am able to do it UIAutomation, but it would be much simpler is there is a direct way

Comment: Added all the properties you can get.
All of them are read only besides name and modifyDate.
To change the name or date simply do: 
$oItem.Name = "New_Name".
Same thing for the date.

Answer (score 2):

Your above script accesses DirectUIHWND. ControlListView sends a command to a ListView32 control.
DirectUIHWND <> ListView32 and it can not be accesses that easily.

This is a "dirty" way to access it:

```
;#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

;Run("explorer.exe")
;Sleep(2000)
Local $hWin = WinGetHandle("Libraries")    ;Change to ProgramData for you
Local $hwnd = ControlGetHandle($hWin, "", "DirectUIHWND3")    ;the name of the list on the left is : SysTreeView321. Hence it is a listTREEview
ConsoleWrite("Window handle: " & $hWin & @LF)
ConsoleWrite("Control handle: " & $hwnd & @LF)
WinActivate($hWin)
ControlFocus($hwnd, "", $hwnd)
Send("{down}{down}{down}")    ;;;select a random item
ConsoleWrite(SysTreeViewGetText() & @LF)




Func SysTreeViewGetText()
    ClipPut("")
    ControlSend($hWnd, "", "", "{F2}")
    ControlSend($hWnd, "", "", "^c")
    ControlSend($hWnd, "", "", "{ESC}")
    Return ClipGet()
EndFunc
```

If you are trying to acces the treeview on the left then check the comments in the example and replace the controlid

You can create a small gui that will list all the files of the folder you want and then make then select from the gui without even having to interact the explorer.exe
Here is an example:

```
#include <File.au3>


Local $aFileList
Local $hGui = GUICreate("ProgramData", 450, 300)
Local $hButton = GUICtrlCreateButton("File list", 180, 50, 100)
Local $hList = GUICtrlCreateList("", 10, 100, 430, 200)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)


While True
    $sMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $sMsg
        Case -3
            Exit
        Case $hButton
            $aFileList = _FileListToArray(@DesktopDir, "*")  ; add your path here
            For $i = 0 To UBound($aFileList) -1
                GUICtrlSetData($hList, $aFileList[$i])
            Next
    EndSwitch
    Sleep(100)
WEnd
```

Comment: +1 for the hack. But this is how I am currently doing it. I was looking for some solution where we can directly retrieve the information of the selected item without involving the clipboard.

Comment: Well to be honest, this is not a hack. This is a solution that i personally would never use.
I would list files to an array and then work from there on.
Again if you dont need to interact the ProgramData window, i repeat there are a lot more better and reliable ways to do whatever you are trying to do ;)

Comment: I added another solution up there but i could help you a lot more if i knew what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: I am sorry. I should have mentioned this in my question. _FileListToArray will also won't work because of the plugin problem. I think the only thing that would work is UIAutomation over here. I found a solution on the autoit forum http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/153520-iuiautomation-ms-framework-automate-chrome-ff-ie/?p=1178018
But the problem with this is it won't read files which are there beyond the scope of the window. i.e files which are visible after scrolling down.

Comment: That is because FindAll method is failing to return elements outside the scope of the window. I might work this around because it seems interesting.

I am not understanding why _FileListToArray wont work. You could get the path of your window then list all files into an array. As i am seeing in the autoit example, this is what you are doing.